# How connecting to remote janus graph from local germlin console?

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, tinkerpop3, janusgraph

We have Janus graph setup on vm and i trying to connect to this remote janus graph and try to run germling queries , but am not able to do that, getting below type of exception when trying to run simepl germlin query

```
g.V()

org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.console.RemoteException: Host did not respond in a timely fashion - check the server status and submit again.
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.jsr223.DriverRemoteAcceptor.submit(DriverRemoteAcceptor.java:188)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:234)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.GremlinGroovysh.execute(GremlinGroovysh.groovy:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:120)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell$leftShift$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:93)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1217)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:144)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:164)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:138)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)


:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml session  , this is thing i am running after connecting germling console using ./germling.sh
```

can someone please help me on this .

Update :

Content from remote.yml file

```
hosts: [MY VM UP ADDRESS]
port: 8182
serializer: { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}
```

Comment: Can you post the content of remote.yaml? Did you change the host to match your VM?

Comment: yes i changes host ip

Comment: You should add more serializers. I don't think Janus work with Gryo by default. Try adding V2 and V3.

Comment: Can you reach the remote port from your machine in general? E.g., does `nc -zvw3 [MY VM UP ADDRESS]` work?